# Magento share product on instagram

Tags: magento, instagram, product, instagram-api, sharing

I need to share magento product link on Instagram like facebook and twitter.
Can anyone provide some idea How to share the product link on Instagram?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Instagram does not allow you post images on behalf of a user. A user would need to launch the application and share it themselves. Please see the documentation: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

However, on a product template you could ask users to share the product and provide them with a selectable URL like so:

`<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>`